# Life as a formal system

Tags: logic, philosophy-of-science, life, formal-theory, formalisation

I am curious if there is some existing work on viewing life as a formal system.
In formal system we have:

- axioms
- and rules of logic (like in math AND, OR)
- then we derive and prove theorems

I see this analogy also in life we have axioms:

- axiom: if you don't drink water you die, or some thing A is poison
- rules of logic
- theorems: if I consume poison A I die. which we can prove now using above axiom and theorems

This way I think all life can be viewed as formal system.
No? Is there some work on it?

Comment: This is not viewing life as a formal system, this is just applying a formal approach to ethics (guidelines on how to live), see [formal ethics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formal_ethics).

Comment: This is not an exact answer to your question, but you may be interested in the works of this man anyway:  Niklas Luhmann.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Niklas_Luhmann I don’t know much about him. Just putting it down as an extra reference for you.

Comment: @Conifold It has nothing to do with ethics. The axioms could be: Jogging is good for your health. Where is ethics here? Theorem could be jogging five times a day is better than four times a day.

Comment: Maybe useful [Joseph Henry Woodger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joseph_Henry_Woodger)'s [The Axiomatic Method in Biology (1937)](https://books.google.it/books/about/The_axiomatic_method_in_biology.html?id=A8I5AAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y)

Comment: But you do not "formalize life": you can try to formalize the "theory of life".

Comment: @user46895 If it has "good" in it, i.e. a judgment of value, it is part of ethics.